# Using Generic in LinkedList that implements Iterable

Tags: java, generics

I want to understand under what circumstances Generics should be used.

Suppose that I want to implement a LinkedList that is iterable. Obviously, the LinkedList should have type parameter that are generic:

Implementation 1:

```
public class LinkedList<E>{
    private Node head;

    private class Node{
        private Node next;
        private E e;
    }
}
```

My first question: should Node also have type parameter E? That is, should the above code be written as:

Implementation 2:

```
public class LinkedList<E>{
    private Node<E> head;

    private class Node<E>{
        private Node<E> next;
        private E e;
    }
}
```

Both implementations compile fine. I have seen implementation 1 in a textbook of mine. Therefore, it seems like implementation 2 is a little unnecessary.

Next, I want to implement Iterable. Suppose we stick with Implementation 1, we will have:

Implementation 3:

```
public class LinkedList<E> implements Iterable<E>{
private Node head;

private class Node{
    private Node next;
    private E e;
}

public Iterator<E> iterator(){
    return new LinkedListIterator();
}

private class LinkedListIterator implements Iterator<E>{
    private Node curr;

    public boolean hasNext(){
        return curr != null;
    }
    public E next(){
        E element = curr.e;
        curr = curr.next;
        return element;
    }
}
```

This is the standard kind of implementation that I have seen in textbooks.

My second question: since we do not have generic type for Node, why can't we not use generic type for the Iterable and Iterator as well? e.g.:

Implementation 4:

```
public class LinkedList1<E> implements Iterable{
    private Node head;

    private class Node{
        private Node next;
        private E e;
    }

    public Iterator iterator(){
        return new LinkedListIterator();
    }

    private class LinkedListIterator implements Iterator{
        private Node curr = head;

        public boolean hasNext(){
            return curr != null;
        }
        public E next(){
            E element = curr.e;
            curr = curr.next;
            return element;
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First question: You are entirely correct, using generics for the inner `Node` class is unnecessary. This is because `Node` is part of `LinkedList<E>`, so it is already implicitly generic, no need to do anything more for that. Had the `Node` class been a separate class outside `LinkedList`, you would have needed to make it generic.

EDIT: To look slightly deeper, your `Node` class really belongs to each instance of `LinkedList<E>`. If you have two linked lists, then `list1.Node` and `list2.Node` are not considered the same class (just as `list1.head` and `list2,head` are not the same variable). This is so no matter if `list1` and `list2` have same or different element types. But it implies that `Node` belongs to an object that already has a type parameter `E`, and you can use that `E` inside `Node` too (unless you redeclare it, in which case you can only use the newly declared `E` and it overshadows the `E` in `LinkedList`).

If you have static declarations in `LinkedList`, the above doesn’t go for them. You already know that a static field is shared by all instances. Had you declared `private static class Node …`, the class would be shared between all linked lists. The logic would still work, but you would have to declare it generic (when you want it to be generic; just the same as classes outside `LinkedList`). Also if you have `public static void main()` in `LinkedList`, since it is static it is not generic even though `LinkedList` is, and as you noted in a comment, if you instantiate `LinkedList` from here, you should give a type parameter. END OF EDIT.

Second question: As you have discovered, you need to pass a type parameter to `Iterable` and `Iterator` interfaces. This is because these are outside your `LinkedList` class and hence not covered by the generic-ness of your class. On the other hand, your `LinkedListIterator` a non-static class is inside `LinkedList` and hence generic because `LinkedList` is and needs not be declared generic in itself.

Comment: I don't quite understand what it means by "Node is part of LinkedList<E>". I know that Node and  LinkedListIterator are inner classes of LinkedList<E> but Iterable is not. I don't quite get how Node "is implicitly generic". For example, suppose that in the main method of LinkedList.java, we try to have "LinkedList<String> ls = new LinkedList<String>(); (put Strings in ls); String str = ls.head.e;", there will be compile time error because "incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to String".